# How can i check if the platform is laptop or desktop on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

What is the most simple way to check if the executing platform is laptop or desktop?
If i need to check the files in /sys/class/power_supply/ which file should i go for?
Thanks

Comment: So what about a "desktop" machine that happens to use a "laptop" CPU and motherboard?

Comment: I need to know how it's done for the most simple case that is a desktop doesn't use any laptop hardware.

Comment: Exactly what of the difference interests you? My laptop is connected to the mains almost all of the time, has a beefy CPU, lots of RAM, a large disk, is connected to wired Ethernet, and to an external keyboard and monitor. I once had a lab with desktop machines with WiFi. Look for the characteristic that is relevant to you, forget about the "form factor."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only think you care about distinguishing laptops from desktops. What you really care about is simply whether `/sys/class/power_supply/` exists.

```
if [ -d "/sys/class/power_supply" ]; then
    # Work with the files in /sys/class/power_supply
fi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my Fujitsu desktop has this directory with one link "hidpp_battery_0" pointing to an entry in /sys/devices/, ie not very useful to distinguish the platforms.

Answer (score 3):

What about checking if there is a Lid?
This should work with Ubuntu – acpi:

```
if [ -d "/proc/acpi/button/lid" ]; then
    echo "computer is a laptop"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the presence of a battery. If it has a battery then Laptop. If not then PC.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run upower to check battery charge level.

LEVEL="$(upower -i $(upower -e | grep 'BAT') | grep -E "percentage" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\%//g')"

if [ $LEVEL -le 100 ]; then

    echo "Device is equipped with a battery and may be a laptop."

else
    echo "Device is NOT equipped with a batter and is likely a desktop."

fi
```

Comment: Or you could check for the existence of `/sys/module/battery`, e.g. `if [ -d "/sys/module/battery" ]; then echo "computer is a laptop"; fi`